# Using default factory property value for other properties within a factory

Tags: laravel, factory, faker

Say that I use a factory to create a model that has 2 properties:

```
$factory->define(MyModel::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'property1' => $faker->numberBetween(1,10),
        'property2' => $faker->numberBetween(1,10)
    ]
}
```

If I set the value of property1: factory('App\MyModel')->create(['property1' => 5]), but also want to use that value in order to calculate the value of property2 (for example have property2 equal property1 + 10), how do I access it inside the factory?

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this to access the previous property,

```
$factory->define(MyModel::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    $property1 = $faker->numberBetween(1,10);
    return [
        'property1' => $property1,
        'property2' => $faker->numberBetween(1,10) + $property1
    ]
}
```

Comment: Tried that before posting here Khalid. The problem is that if I set property1 via the create() method, the newly created model will be instantiated with this value, but property2 will use the random  $property1 value set inside the factory.

Comment: @LiamArbel for that you can use last inserted item value instead of faker's value